# When, if ever, is this a valid universal property for $A \times (B_1 + B_2)$? (Category Theory)

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

**Notation:** Let $\pi$'s denote canonical projections, $j$'s denote canonical injections, given a pair of maps $X \overset{f_1}{\to} Y_1$ and $X \overset{f_2}{\to} Y_2$ denote the unique map $X \overset{f}{\to} Y_1 \times Y_2$ s.t. $\pi_1 \circ f = f_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ f = f_2$ by $\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle$, then given $X_1 \overset{f_1}{\to} Y_1$ and $X_2 \overset{f_2}{\to}Y_2$ let $X_1 \times X_2 \overset{f_1 \times f_2}{\to} Y_1 \times Y_2$ denote $\langle f_1 \circ \pi_1, f_2 \circ \pi_2 \rangle$.

> **Question:** In a category where sums and products exist, when, if ever, does the object $A \times (B_1 + B_2)$ satisfy the following universal property?
>
> - For every pair of maps $A \overset{f_1}{\to} C_1$, $B_1 + B_2 \overset{f_2}{\to} C_2$, there exists exactly one map $A \times (B_1 + B_2) \overset{f}{\to} C_1 \times C_2$ such that $f \circ (1_A \times j_1) = f_1 \times (f_2 \circ j_1)$ and $f \circ (1_A \times j_2)= f_1 \times (f_2 \circ j_2)$.
>   In other words, given any $A \times (B_1 + B_2) \overset{g}{\to} C_1 \times C_2$ with $g \circ (1_A \times j_1) = f_1 \times (f_2 \circ j_1)$ and $g \circ (1_A \times j_2)= f_1 \times (f_2 \circ j_2)$, it follows that $g = f_1 \times f_2 = f$.

A seemingly necessary condition for this is that the canonical projections $\pi_i$ be epimorphisms, and a sufficient condition for that necessary condition is that the category has a zero object according to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238995/are-all-projection-maps-in-a-categorical-product-epic). The above also seems like it would be a special case of something like:

- For every pair of maps $A_1 \overset{f_1}{\to} C_1$, $A_2 \overset{f_2}{\to} C_2$, there is exactly one map $A_1 \times A_2 \overset{f}{\to} C_1 \times C_2$ such that $f=f_1 \times f_2$, and $f = g_1 \times g_2$ implies that $f_1 = g_1$ and $f_2 = g_2$.

(Since we have in the case that $A_2 = B_1 + B_2$ by the universal product of the sum that $g \circ j_1 = f_2 \circ j_1$ and $g \circ j_2 = f_2 \circ j_2$ implies that $g = f_2$.) Obviously one such map exists, so what would need to be shown is that $g_1 \times g_2 = \langle g_1 \circ \pi^A_1, g_2 \circ \pi^A_2 \rangle = \langle f_1 \circ \pi^A_1, f_2 \circ \pi^A_2 \rangle = f_1 \times f_2$ implies that $f_1 = g_1$ and $f_2 = g_2$. By the universal property of the product I think this already implies that $f_1 \circ \pi_1^A = g_1 \circ \pi_1^A$ and $f_2 \circ \pi_A^2 = g_2 \circ \pi_A^2$, so if $\pi_1^A$ and $\pi_2^A$ are epic then we're done.

**Context:** I am trying to show that in a Cartesian closed category with sums and products, the standard map $A \times B_1 + A \times B_2 \overset{s}{\to} A \times (B_1 + B_2)$ has an inverse, call it $t$, defined using the universal property of the exponential object.

I have been able to show that $t \circ s = 1_{A \times B_1 + A \times B_2}$ quite easily, by showing that $(t \circ s) \circ J_1 = J_1$ and $(t \circ s) \circ J_2 = J_2$ (where $J_1$ and $J_2$ are the corresponding injections $\to A \times B_1 + A \times B_2$).

However, I have not been able to show that $s \circ t = 1_{A \times (B_1 + B_2)}$. I had tried to do this by showing that $\pi_1 \circ (s \circ t) = \pi_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ (s \circ t) = \pi_2$, but the left expressions don't seem to simplify at all. However, it is quite easy to show that $(s \circ t) \circ (1_A \times j_1) = 1_A \times j_1$ and $(s \circ t) \circ (1_A \times j_2) = 1_A \times j_2$. ($j_i$ denote the injections $B_1 + B_2$.) So ideally if it is true that $1_{A \times (B_1 + B_2)}$ is the unique $f$ such that $f \circ (1_A \times j_1) = 1_A \times j_1$ and $f \circ (1_A \times j_2) = 1_A \times j_2$, and if I can show that this is true, then I would be done. It seems intuitively plausible, but I'm stuck trying to come up with either a counterexample or a proof (hence the above question).

Comment: As an alternative way of establishing the result, you can note that cartesian closure means $A\times -$ is a left adjoints. Left adjoints preserve colimits and thus, in particular, coproducts. You can spell out this general proof to get the concrete isomorphism. A different alternative proof is to simply write out what the inverse would be using the simply typed lambda calculus and then translate that to categorical operations.

Comment: @DerekElkins This is a dumb question, but to which isomorphism are you referring? Or which result? The distributive law in a cartesian closed category? Or the faux universal property which I wish was true? I think the concrete isomorphism for the distributive law I am using may correspond to what you are describing, but the authors (I am following Part V of Lawvere and Schanuel's Conceptual Mathematics) don't describe the one-to-one correspondence between morphisms $X \to Y^T$ and $T \times X \to Y$ in terms of adjoints, although that seems to be what adjointness refers to in this context.

Comment: Yes, the distributive law was what I was referring to. I could have made that clearer. A *natural* correspondence between $X\to Y^T$ and $T\times X\to Y$ natural in $X$ and $Y$ is exactly what it means for $T\times -$ to be left adjoint to $(-)^T$. (At least it's the definition of adjunction I prefer.) It's pretty easy to prove that left adjoints preserve colimits given just this definition and the characterization of colimits via representability. The upshot for you might be to realize that the answer doesn't really depend on the exact functors involved or the exact colimit.